# chrome.storage get set order

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am currently working with `chrome.storage.sync.get` and `chrome.storage.sync.set`. The problem that I am getting is that I want to make my function

**get -> set -> get -> set**

. But what it really does is

**get -> get -> set -> set**,

and this messes up my code. Is there any way to make chrome.storage.sync.get and chrome.storage.sync.set to work in an order that I set and want to be?

Comment: The API is asynchronous. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321) and [the overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#sync).

Answer (score 0):

you could use Promises to execute async calls in the sequqnce you need

```
function getStorage (key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(key, (value)=>{
            if(chrome.runtime.lastError){
                return reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            }
            return  resolve(value);
        })
    });
}

function setStorage (item) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.storage.sync.set(item, ()=>{
            if(chrome.runtime.lastError){
                return reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            }
            return  resolve();
        })
    });
}

getStorage('key')
    .then(value => {
        setStorage({key2:"value2"})
    })
    //...
    .catch(err => {
       //handle err 
    });
```